# switch to a 64 bit mode?

Tags: pi-3b+

I have an old B+ which I think is 32 bit but curious if this can be switched to a 64 bit mode??

Does this info help at all?

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:                    armv7l
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
Vendor ID:                       ARM
Model:                           4
Model name:                      Cortex-A53
Stepping:                        r0p4
CPU max MHz:                     1400.0000
CPU min MHz:                     600.0000
BogoMIPS:                        38.40
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Retbleed:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Not affected
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Not affected
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

also this

```
$ uname -m
armv7l
```

I what i am most interested in is to see if my pi can handle this OS developer tutorial in Rust but it looks like the tutorial requires an arm8 board and 64 bit pi. Any tips appreciated, not a lot of wisdom here:
https://github.com/rust-embedded/rust-raspberrypi-OS-tutorials#%E2%84%B9%EF%B8%8F-introduction

Comment: Why not just flash Pi OS Bookworm 64 bit to a spare sd card? https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

Comment: can you explain that more? re-flash my pi to Bookworm? On the Raspberry Pi Imager I could just select that option of Bookworm in 64 bit?

Comment: You can't flash the sd card you have booted from. You use Pi Imager to flash a spare sd card in a usb adapter or sd card slot. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#install-an-operating-system

Answer (score 1):

That `armv7l` tag is misleading; that's a Pi 3 (quad core Cortex-A53, ARMv8), the CPU is 64-bit, and **yes, you can run a pure 64-bit OS on it** (and/or do ARMv8 bare metal stuff).

I notice the fritzing diagram near the bottom of that github page shows a board that is explicitly a Pi 3B.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 3B+ - hardly old, which does support 64bit but unless you need to run software which is only available as 64bit there is no reason to change (you won't see any difference in performance).

I would suggest you avoid Bookworm which has limitations on Pi4 and is not yet recommended for earlier models.

I have been using Bullseye 64bit on a Pi3B+